# mongodb query an array inside a document with an and clause

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

i have an array which includes the userid and the current date. My Query should return all results where the userid equals my userid and the date should be less than another date. This is how i tried it:

```
{ participantData: { $not: { $gte: firstDay }}, userid: userid }
```

The query isnt returning any data. Please find attached a screenshot how the document looks like:
[image: should return this doc]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) so you can filter by matching criteria within the same element of an array

```
{ participantData: { $elemMatch: { userid: "xyz", date: { $lte: firstDay } } } }
```